# XE6 How do you check if a UnicodeString is null?

Tags: c++builder, unicode-string, c++builder-xe6

I'm using `C++ Builder XE6`. I'm getting a `UnicodeString` as a parameter and I wish to check if the string is set to NULL, and not an empty string.

I've tried to do some simple compares to see if the param is null, but seem to be failing. I'm using the `==` operator which doesn't seem to be working, which makes me think it is overloaded.

I've tried:

```
if (searchString == NULL)
```

In the debugger view, it shows the value of `{ NULL }` in the local variables. If I add the variable to the watch list, then it shows it has a property of "Data" which is `NULL`.

[image]

Any ideas on how I can properly do the compare?

Comment: Are `NULL` and empty string treated the same? I did a check of the NULL string against "" and the if caught it. I'm curios if there is a way to distinguish between NULL and empty string though...

Comment: There is no difference between "null" and "empty" in `UnicodeString`. They are the same thing. To check if a `UnicodeString` is empty, you can either check `==""`, check if `Length()==0`, or call `IsEmpty()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no such thing as a `NULL` value for a `UnicodeString`. A string is a series of characters, but `NULL` is a pointer (well - actually it is a macro that evaluates to an int, `0`, but it is supposed to be used to indicate null pointers if your compiler doesn't support `nullptr`).

Internally, the `data` member of `UnicodeString` is NULL when the string is empty, and non-NULL when the string has at least 1 character.

To check if the string is empty, use the `IsEmpty()` method, which checks if the `data` member is NULL or not. There is only one empty state; there is no distinction between "empty" and "null" like some languages have.

The value you see in the debugger is the internal `data` member of `UnicodeString`, it is not a part of `UnicodeString`'s interface. When you see NULL in the debugger, you should treat it as being an empty string.