# TIniFile->ReadString returns null instead of ""

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

I have this piece of code that refuses to return "DefaultVal" when "CurrentFile" is empty:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
      TIniFile *pIni = new TIniFile("c:\\Test\\MyIni.ini");
      try
         {
         int i = pIni->ReadInteger (L"x", L"Level",  0);  //This is ok

         UnicodeString s = pIni->ReadString ("x", "CurrentFile",  "DefaultVal");   //Debugger shows s = NULL
         }
      __finally
         {
         pIni->Free();
         }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is the INI file:

```
[x]
CurrentFile=
```

If I edit the INI file to `CurrentFile= "something"` then the code works and s correctly contains "something".

What am I doing wrong?

C++ Builder Tokyo 10.3.2

Comment: oh... I guess a unicodestring that is set to NULL means that it is empty????

Comment: Yes, in Delphi, an empty string (UnicodeString, AnsiString) is returned as NULL (nil). Not sure how that works in C++Builder. But since you are calling a Delphi function, you can expect NULL (nil) to be returned.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis = Actually, in Delphi, the debugger will show you "" for an empty string, while in c++ the debugger will show you NULL for an empty string.

Comment: I think it is more like `{ NULL }`, i.e. a struct with NULL as only element. AFAIK, in C++Builder, these strings are structs or classes, while in Delphi, they are built-in types. The C++Builder structs or classes mimic these built-in types.

Comment: Yes, in C++, `(Ansi|Wide|Unicode)String` are classes with a single `Data` member, that is NULL when the string is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TIniFile::ReadString()` returns the `Default` value only if the specified `Ident` value does not exist at all.  If the `Ident` value exists but is blank, or there is an error reading it, a blank string is returned instead.  If you want your `Default` value to be used if the `Ident` value is blank, you will have to check for that manually, eg:

```
String s = pIni->ReadString (_D("x"), _D("CurrentFile"), _D("")); 
if (s.IsEmpty()) // or: if (s == _D(""))
    s = _D("DefaultVal");
```

Note that `TIniFile::ReadInteger()` returns the `Default` value if the `Ident` value can't be converted to an `int` for *any* reason, whether that be because it does not exist, it is blank, it cannot be read, it is not in numerical hexadecimal format, etc.

Answer (score 0):

My question is stupid but I won't delete it. Let others learn from it too.  It was my Delphi brain trying wrap around the weird C++ concepts :)

Delphi-style strings (`AnsiString`, `RawByteString`, `UnicodeString`, and `WideString`) are not actually NULL in C++Builder, EVEN though this is what the debugger shows. In other words, whenever your debugger shows `NULL` for such a string, think of it as an "empty string" instead.

To be noted also that

```
if (s == NULL)
```

does not return what you expect. Use `s.IsEmpty()` instead.

Here is the complete answer:

[XE6 How do you check if a UnicodeString is null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25294762/xe6-how-do-you-check-if-a-unicodestring-is-null)

Comment: The reason `if (s == NULL)` doesn't work is because `NULL` is defined as `0`, so `if (s == 0)` converts the `0` to a string before then comparing it, so you are really doing `if (s == "0")` instead